# Using suppose as a verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence

Here supposition is used as a noun. How can I transform this sentence using "suppose" as a verb?

◆  **It seems a reasonable supposition.**

Comment: It seems reasonable to suppose that you could come up with a way to do this, if you think about it a little.

Comment: @HotLicks One could reasonably suppose that you are quite a comedian.

Comment: @RichardKayser - My wife doesn't think so.

Comment: @HotLicks Better luck next time!

Comment: You're right @HotLicks.  I didn't think of it that way.

Comment: "That which has been supposed seems reasonable" is about as close as I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple exercise

I will alter the words of the sentence as little as possible.

Before (noun):

> It seems a reasonable **supposition**.

After (verb):

> They **supposed** something reasonably.

---

### Analysis

To address a comment, I am providing a detailed analysis of the wording I chose.

---

My interpretation here is based on the second sense of [**supposition**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposition):

> **2** : the act of supposing

In other words, I take it to mean it was the **enactment** that was reasonable.

As such, I extrapolate back to the act actually being performed, and I replace the adjective *reasonable* with the adverb *reasonably*.

I am deliberately describing **how** somebody supposed the thing.

---

Here are the events in chronological order as I see them, put alongside an analogous sentence using the same interpretation.

As it happened in front of spectators:

> They **supposed** something ***reasonably***.
>   He **read** the story ***thoughtfully***.

Spectator commentary on the event:

> It seems a ***reasonable*** **supposition**.
>   It seems a ***thoughtful*** **reading**.

Comment: On a default reading, this says that their reasoning powers were pretty sound, not that the supposition is one a reasonable person might assume. It's also not too idiomatic: not always fatal, but when twinned with ambiguity, it's better avoided. 'It seems reasonable to suppose' is also not very idiomatic, but _is_ unambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [*Supposition*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposition): "**2** : the act of supposing." (*It seems a reasonable [**act** of supposing].*)

Comment: Relevance? 'They reasonably supposed that ...' tells us something about the reasonableness of the act of supposing mentioned in the first instance. 'It seems a reasonable supposition that' highlights the plausibility of what is supposed rather than the proficiency of the judgement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have now expanded my answer considerably in order to explain exactly why I chose the wording I did, and what it means.

Comment: Doubtless sense (1) of supposition from the anonymous dictionary is 'something assumed'; the only definition of 'reasonable assumption' I have found gives the illustration 'It is a reasonable supposition that many mothers would welcome the offer of part time work.' [[TheAcademicLawDictionary](https://law.academic.ru/53055/reasonable_supposition)] which obviously tallies with the default definition.

Comment: It seems you pulled *they* out of thin air, thereby introducing new meaning. And where did the sense of *seems* go?

Comment: @TinfoilHat What pronoun should I have used? There had to have been a subject for the verb. *It* would have been strange, and either *he* or *she* would be assuming a gender and singularity. *They* is at least gender neutral and ambiguous when it comes to plurality. It was the least *intrusive* reimagining of the original sentence I could think of. Also, *seems* doesn't make sense at the time of speaking about what a subject did if using it in the context I did. This was best way I could think of to use the verb while making the least number of changes I could.

Comment: "They supposed something reasonable." Using *reasonably* changes the meaning a little.

Answer (score 0):

Is suppose anything but a verb? Mind you, verbs are being increasingly used as nouns - e.g. you are a total fail - and in that way we could say it was a false suppose on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Your verb here is *seems*, so you need to retain that somehow to keep the sense. Let's try this . . .

> Before: *It seems a reasonable supposition.* (*supposition* is a noun)
>
> After: *It seems reasonably supposed.* (*seems supposed* is a passive
>   verb construction)

Comment: While I guess this is technically correct, it appears to take away from the spirit of the question, which focuses on *suppose*, not *seem*. Here, *suppose* is not being used as an active verb in any way—and it could be argued it's used an an adjectival sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford: In *seems supposed*, *seem* is an auxiliary verb and *suppose* is a main verb — best of both worlds with respect to the original meaning. And we don't know who did the supposing, hence the passive verb construction.  I think would be a long stretch to conjure an adjectival reading of *supposed* here.

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can interpret it that way, but it's definitely ambiguous. When you say *It is **composed**,* it does not have to mean that it was composed **by** someone. It can refer to the actual state of something. In the same way, *supposed* can be adjectival. This isn't even a stretch. Look at the definition of [*supposed*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposed) as an adjective, meaning *alleged* or *believed*. (*It is a **supposed** truth that …*)  With the primary emphasis the verb *seem*, your sentence is too ambiguous to be a good example of what was asked for.

Comment: *Supposed* as an attributive adjective is normal. That is the only use demonstrated in the OED — for one. Otherwise, it's a verb.

Comment: There is no such thing as an *attributive adjective*. There are *attributive nouns* and verbs that act *adjectively*. In this case, *supposed* actually ***is*** an adjective. The fact that it's spelled the same when the verb is used in the past just means that the word, as spelled, can be taken to mean two different things if you look at it differently. (In other words, as in this case, it's *ambiguous*.) But the adjective **supposed** ***is*** an actual, real adjective, as *any* dictionary will attest to.

Comment: Of course there is such thing as an attributive adjective: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-adjective-1689145. And that is what *supposed* actually and really is. I see very few dictionaries describing *supposed* as a predicate adjective.

Comment: You got me. I've never heard of those categories of adjective before. But if you're saying that you're using it as an *attributive* adjective (which is "normal'), then you're saying that you're using it as adjective rather than as a verb (which is what was requested). Either that, or you're admitting that in your usage it's not obviously a verb.

Comment: No, I am referring to your example, in which  you used *supposed* attributively as an adjective: *It is a supposed truth that . . .* That's how *supposed* can be an adjective. My example is a passive verb; *supposed* is just not a predicate adjective, even under the most imaginative of circumstances. And that is something that many, if not most dictionaries agree on (not that dictionaries can be trusted much with labels, either way).

Comment: I did not use it *attributively **as** an adjective*. Go to any dictionary and look at it. It ***is*** an adjective. It even has a relatively large number of senses in its grammatical role of adjective. And while you may be *intending* to use it as a passive verb, it's role in that sentence is ambiguous to anybody else reading it. It can go either way. The very fact that we've had so much debate over it indicates that you are not using the word in a clear-cut and obvious way. The question here is asking that the focus be on the verb; so use it as an *active* verb that has that focus.

Comment: The OED — for one — does not list *supposed* as an adjective. The OP says nothing about "focus." A passive verb form is a verb, just like any other. What the passive voice does not do is focus on the agent, which, in any case, was not supplied by the OP.

Comment: Your statement is factually incorrect. Here is Oxford's entry for the [***adjective*** *reserved*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reserved). I don't have access to the paywall version of the OED, but Lexico provides Oxford's smaller public subset. I will no longer be providing comments here.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke in that last comment; the OED does not list *supposed* as a **predicate** adjective. As I said previously above, it lists nothing but an *attributive* use for *supposed* as an adjective (I looked). Same for Lexico: https://www.lexico.com/definition/supposed